# How to invoke private method via Reflection when parameter of method is List?

Tags: java, reflection

How can I invoke private method via Reflection API?

My code

```
public class A {
    private String method(List<Integer> params){
        return "abc";
    }
}
```

And test

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<A> clazz = A.class;
        Method met = clazz.getMethod("method", List.class);
        met.setAccessible(true);
        String res = (String) met.invoke("method", new ArrayList<Integer>());
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? I can see one potential one: for invoking an _instance_ method of a class you need ... well ... an instance of that class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two problems in your code

- you are using `getMethod` which can only return `public` methods, to get private ones use `getDeclaredMethod` on type which *declares* it.
- you are invoking your method on `"method"` String literal instead of instance of `A` class (String doesn't have this method, so you can't invoke it on its instance. For now your code is equivalent to something like `"method".method(yourList)` which is not correct).

Your code should look like

```java
Class<A> clazz = A.class;
Method met = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("method", List.class);
//                    ^^^^^^^^
met.setAccessible(true);
String res = (String) met.invoke(new A(), new ArrayList<Integer>());
//                               ^^^^^^^ 

//OR pass already existing instance of A class
A someA = new A(); // instance of A on which you want to call the method
// ╰╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╴╮
String res = (String) met.invoke(someA, new ArrayList<Integer>());

System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in this way if you need to create an Instance of the `A` by reflection too

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> aClass = A.class;
    Constructor<?> constructor = aClass.getConstructors()[0];
    Object a = constructor.newInstance(); // create instance of a by reflection
    Method method = a.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("method", List.class); // getDeclaredMethod for private
    method.setAccessible(true); // to enable accessing private method
    String result = (String) method.invoke(a, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    System.out.println(result);
  }
```